# Counting output

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def leap_years(start, end):
    if start < 1500 or start > 2100:
        return
    if end < 1500 or end > 2100:
        return
    i = 0
    for i in range(start, end + 1):
        if i % 4 == 0 and (i % 100 != 0 or i % 400 == 0):
            print(i)


print(leap_years(1998, 2008))
```

I want to output be 3 and not 2000,2004,2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good place to consider a list comprehension to create a list of leap years:

```
def leap_years(start, end):
    if start < 1500 or start > 2100:
        return
    if end < 1500 or end > 2100:
        return

    leaps = [ i for i in range(start, end+1) if i % 4 == 0 and (i % 100 != 0 or i % 400 == 0) ]

    print( len(leaps) )

leap_years(1998,2008)
```

Result is:
3

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a *counter*:

```
def leap_years(start, end):
    if start < 1500 or start > 2100:
        return 0
    if end < 1500 or end > 2100:
        return 0
    i, count = 0, 0
    for i in range(start, end + 1):
        if i % 4 == 0 and (i % 100 != 0 or i % 400 == 0):
            count += 1
    return count

print(leap_years(1998, 2008))
```

**Output**

```
3
```

In the above code the *counter* is the variable `count` each time the leap year condition is met it increments by `1`. Note that now the function `leap_years` returns the amount of leap years.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sum(...)` here to count the number of elements:

```
def leap_years(start, end):
    if not 1500 < start < 2100:
        return 0
    if not 1500 < end < 2100:
        return 0
    return sum(
        (not y % 4 and y % 100 != 0) or not y % 400
        for y in range(start, end + 1)
    )
```

This works since in Python `True` is equal to `1`, and `False` to `0`, so we count the number of elements.

The above is however not very efficient: we can in fact calculate the number of leap years over huge ranges, without having to iterate over them.

We can for example calculate the number of elements dividably by `4` between `a` and `b` (both inclusive), by calculating `((b - c)/4) + 1` where `c` is the *next* element dividable by `4`.

With the same logic we can exclude the number of elements dividable by 100, and include the ones dividably by 400, like:

```
def num_div(div, frm, to):
    return max(0, (to - (frm + (div - frm) % div) + div) // div)

def leap_years(start, end):
    return num_div(4, start, end) - num_div(100, start, end) + num_div(400, start, end)
```

For example, given the Gregorian calendar with these rules always existed, the number of leap years between 1234 AD and 123'456'789 AD is:

```
>>> leap_years(1234, 123456789)
29937972
```